# Why doesn't inner tbody stretch?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with table. This is my code:

```html
<table class="employers__table">
     <thead>
          <tr>
             <td>Таб. №</td>
             <td>Сотрудник / СИЗ</td>
             <td>Разм. ряд</td>
             <td>Кол.</td>
             <td>Ед. изм.</td>
             <td>Дата выдачи</td>
             <td>Дата замены</td>
             <td>Списать СИЗ</td>
             <td>Продлить СИЗ</td>
         </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
        <tbody class="label">
            <tr>
               <td colspan="9">
                   Aaa
               </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

```css
.employers__table {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.label tr > td {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Inner `<tbody>` doesn't stretch. [This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPUKn.jpg).

Why does this happen?

I tried to create a table with the same structure in the new project, and it worked there...I don't understand.

Comment: why do you have nested `<tbody>` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are basically going against the basic semantics of [HTML TABLE](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3).

It allows you to have multiple `<tbody>` inside a `table`, but not nested `tbody`

```
<TABLE>
<THEAD>
     <TR> ...header information...
</THEAD>
<TFOOT>
     <TR> ...footer information...
</TFOOT>
<TBODY>
     <TR> ...first row of block one data...
     <TR> ...second row of block one data...
</TBODY>
<TBODY>
     <TR> ...first row of block two data...
     <TR> ...second row of block two data...
     <TR> ...third row of block two data...
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

**Corrected Snippet**

```css
.employers__table {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.label tr>td {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<table class="employers__table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Таб. №</td>
      <td>Сотрудник / СИЗ</td>
      <td>Разм. ряд</td>
      <td>Кол.</td>
      <td>Ед. изм.</td>
      <td>Дата выдачи</td>
      <td>Дата замены</td>
      <td>Списать СИЗ</td>
      <td>Продлить СИЗ</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="label">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="9">
        Aaa
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I know that. But I need to do a table with collapsive rows. So I read this [article](https://webdesignerhut.com/data-table-with-collapsible-table-rows/) and tried to do the same. In the article the author uses nested `<tbody>` for this purpose.

Comment: well, the semantics is from `W3C` which is the reference doc for web devs. It's possible to go against the semantics described, but that comes with unexpected outcomes.

Comment: So what do I have to do to fix my problem? I need to create a table with two nested `<tbody>` - first with class `label`, second with class `dropdown`. Then after clicking on `<tr>` in first `<tbody>`, the second `<tbody>` should open. It's easy. But nested tbody don't stretch.

Comment: so what happens if you dont nest 2 `<tbody>` and have both of them i same level?

Comment: Yes, it works then. But my problem is that I'm using Vue.js in the project, and I need to do something like this `<tbody v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">...</tbody>`, so I can't paste dropdown `<tbody>` between them. That's why I'm trying to do something like this `<tbody v-for="item in items" :key="item.id"><tbody class="label"></tbody><tbody class="dropdown"></tbody></tbody>

Comment: @LLIaJIyH so, I think we have figured the initial issue. The current issue is related to `vue.js` which needs to go under that tag as a different question mate. Please feel free to paste the url of the new question here as well